# Easy way to make an Object[][] from an ArrayList<Object> with the fields of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, arraylist, jtable

So I have this `ArrayList` filled with Objects and I need to convert it to an `Object[][]` to put it easily in a `JTable`.

Example :

I have an `ArrayList<Animal>`:

```
class Animal{
    String color;
    int age;
    String eatsGrass;
    // Rest of the Class (not important)
}
```

What I want from this is a JTable with the following column names :

```
Color - Age - Eats Grass?
```

My current method looks like this :

```
List<Animal> ani = new ArrayList();
// Fill the list
Object[][] arrayForTable = new Object[ani.size()][3];

for (int i = 0 ; i < ani.size() ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++){
        switch(j){
        case 1 : arrayForTable[i][j] = ani.get(j).getColor();break;
        case 2 : arrayForTable[i][j] = ani.get(j).getAge();break;
        default : arrayForTable[i][j] = ani.get(j).getEatsGrass();break;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine but is there an easier way to make this possible. I can not imagine myself using the same method for a `JTable` with 25 columns for example.

Comment: A better approach would be to use a `TableModel` suitable for your backing data type

Comment: @SteveKuo Yes, it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `Animal` class.

```
public Object[] getDataArray() {
    return new Object[]{color, age, eatsGrass};
}
```

Then, use a `TableModel`.

```
String columns[] = {"Color", "Age", "Eats Grass?"}; 

DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);

for (Animal animal : ani) {
    tableModel.addRow(animal.getDataArray());
}

JTable animalTable = new JTable(tableModel);
```

Comment: Thanks ! Using a tableModel is certainly the best way to do this. Accepted !

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new method in your `Animal` class would certainly help you:

```
public Object[] getAttributesArray() {
    return new Object[]{color, age, eatsGrass};
}
```

And then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ani.size(); i++){
    arrayForTable[i] = ani.get(i).getAttributesArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Bright idea indeed !

Answer (score 0):

what about just

```
   for (int i = 0 ; i < ani.size() ; i++){
            arrayForTable[i] = new Object[]{
             ani.get(i).getColor(), ani.get(i).getAge(),ani.get(i).getEatsGrass()};
}
```

Comment: Upvote because it answers the question, but what if I have 100 fields?

Comment: @YassinHajaj if your class animal will have 100 fields, you will have same problem with any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < ani.size(); i++) {
Animal animal = ani.get(i);
arrayForTable[i] = new Object[] {animal.getColor(), animal.getAge(), animal. getEatsGrass()};
}
```